# Python 3.5 OrderedDict: applying sorted to a nested dictionary iterator

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

So the python documentation suggests using `itemgetter`, `attrgetter`, or `methodgetter` from the `operator` module when applying `sorted` on complex data types. Further, `iterators` are smaller and faster than lists for large size objects.

Thus I am wondering how to create an `iterator` on an `OrderDict`'s *values*. The reason being that in the `OrderDict` I wish to sort all the values are also (regular) dictionaries.

For regular dictionaries, one could do this with:

```
sorted(my_dict.itervalues(), key=itemgetter('my_key'))
```

however `OrderedDict` only seems to have the method `__iter__()` which works on the `OrderedDict` keys.

So how can I efficiently make an iterator for the values of the `OrderedDict`.

Note, I am not looking for list comprehension, a lambda function, or extracting the relevant sub key (key inside the dictionary (a value)) values of the `OrderedDict`.

e.g.

```
sorted (my_dict, key= lambda key: my_dict[key]['my_key'])
```

example nested:

```
test = OrderedDict({'a': {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}, 
                    'b': {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
                    })
```

Comment: If this is really Python 3, you don't need `itervalues()`, as `dict.values()` is *already* an iterable. In Python 3, `dict.itervalues()` *doesn't exist*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `OrderedDict.values` is of type `class odict_values`

Comment: Do you have an example of the OrderedDict you got ?

Comment: @user312016 added

Comment: @MartijnPieters also for the regular dictionary, `dict.values` is a `view` not an iterator

Comment: The point was that `itervalues` doesn't exist. Using the values view is the correct option; you merely need an iterable, `sorted()` will request the iterator for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to call the method `.values()` to get a `view` and type set it to `iter`:

```
sorted(iter(my_dict.values()), key=itemgetter('my_subkey'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither `dict` nor `OrderedDict` have an `itervalues()` method in Python 3. That method only exists in Python 2.

Use `dict.values()`:

```
sorted(my_dict.values(), key=itemgetter('my_key'))
```

In Python 2 you want to use `itervalues()` not so much because it is an iterator, but because `dict.values()` had to create a new list object which is then discarded again. Iterables are also not faster (rather, they are often slower!), they are instead more memory efficient. In this case it is faster because not having to create a (large) list that you then discard again takes time.

In Python 3, `dict.values()` creates a view instead, a lightweight object that *like `dict.itervalues()`* yields values on demand and doesn't have to produce a list up front.

You don't have to call `iter()` on this. `sorted()` takes an *iterable*, and will itself call `iter()` on whatever you passed in. Because it does this from native code and doesn't have to look up a global name, it can do this much faster than Python code ever could.